# Finding the interval between two pointers to a tab in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, element

I'd like to know how many element I have between two pointers to a tab, with a function.

For example in this code, nb would be 20.

```
int main(void)
{
  int t[50] = {0};
  int nb;

  nb = finding_number_element(&t[10], &t[30]);
  return (0);
}
```

Have you got a idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for... what do you mean by "tab"? Your demonstration is returning "20", so you want the number of "elements" (being `int`s in this case) between two memory locations?

Comment: There are a few things you could help to clarify/define: What are your definitions for interval, element, and tab?

Comment: Exactly Mike, I'd like to have the number of "elements" between two memory locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int finding_number_element(int *a, int *b) 
{
  return (b - a);
}
```

if a and b will be pointers to the same array this should work.

Comment: Would be prettier to make the pointers `const`, and return `ptrdiff_t`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something that doesn't care about the data type of t

```
#define ele_size(x) sizeof(x[0])

int main(void)
{
    int t[50] = {0};

    int nb;
    nb = finding_number_element(ele_size(t),&t[10], &t[30]);
    return (0);
}

int finding_number_element(unsigned int ui_ele_size, void *a, void *b) 
{
    unsigned int ui_pointer1 = (unsigned int)a;
    unsigned int ui_pointer2 = (unsigned int)b;

    return ((b - a)/ui_ele_size);

}
```